# Javascript Try Catch vs Catch chain

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, try-catch

I recently ran into a Javascript problem catching errors and thus crashing when exception thrown.

- `funcReturnPromise().then().catch()`

I had to change this to:

```
try {
  funcReturnPromise().then()
} catch (e) {
  ...
}
```

Couldn't find a decent explanation for it, any JS wizards available to enlighten a JS peasant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `funcReturnPromise()` can throw synchronously (which functions that return promises should generally never do), then you do have to catch that synchronous exception with try/catch as you discovered when using regular `.then()`.

This is one place where `async` functions can hep you.  For example, if you declare `funcReturnPromise` as `async`, then the synchronous exception it throws will automatically become a rejected promise and the caller won't ever be exposed to a synchronous exception.

Or, if the caller (your code here) uses await, then you can catch both sycnhronous exceptions and rejected promises with the same `try/catch`.

So, for example, you could do this:

```
async function myFunc()
    try {
      let result = await funcReturnPromise();
      console.log(result);
    } catch (e) {
        // this catches both a rejected promise AND
        // a synchronously thrown exception
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this explanation is detailed and clear - the error was indeed being thrown synchronously

Comment: yep thanks, I couldn't accept it before due to 10 minute grace period

Comment: @Luffy - Cool, glad we got it all explained.